# How to resolve yarn warnings

Tags: vue.js, webpack, eslint, yarnpkg, less-loader

I created a new project with the vue cli.
This project is a Vue3 with Ant Design, Vue Router and Eslint.
However when I give the yarn command it shows me the following warnings.

```
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb > eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.13.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=1.11.0".
warning " > less-loader@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 26.91s.
```

The webpack I noticed is already installed directly on vue 3. How do I resolve these warnings?

Comment: Have you tried just using npm instead of yarn.

Comment: add peerDependancies on the you package.json dependancies

Answer (score 0):

for **fsevents** it seems that it's a MacOS-only library so that might explain why you got the first error.

for **peer dependencies and webpack** if you are using Yarn it seems that you have to do `yarn add webpack --peer` or as @kaumadie said in a comment you can also add it directly on the *package.json* file of your project

With npm, you can do `npm i` directly in the project's folder and it should resolve all peer dependencies automatically

Hope it helped you, and have a good day !

Comment: it didn't work, so it looks like the vue cli already creates the project with a version of the webpack that doesn't appear in package.json. This version is causing this warning.